# A word for a place that produces food from animals

Tags: terminology

I looking for a word, if exists, for a place where the animals like cow, pig and chicken are killed, cleaned and have its meat and parts processed into bagged foods like bacon, ham, beef, etc. 
In Portuguese we have a word "Frigorífico" for it, and translating this word I found theses meanings: Frigorific or Fridge. But, it seems to be incorrect to me.

Comment: A `slaughterhouse` or a `meat packing plant` could be what you're looking for.

Comment: I think maybe it can be 'meat packing plant'. Even both words seems to define just sectors of this kind of "Industry".

Comment: On top of what tushar said consider also "meat processing plant"

Comment: A shambles. That is the word in 1600 kjv bible

Comment: @Kris Except it's not a word than anyone 500 years later would use for this.  Let's assume the OP is not a time-traveller from 1600. ;)

Comment: @sertage  Please can you precise if you're writing for an average Joe or for people familiar with the industry (or educated  people who would be willing to expand their vocabulary by looking up a word) . It 'll help get you a better answer.

Comment: a "meatpackers" or just "packers" is the equivalent word in English, that's it.

Comment: @Graham: Are you then a time-traveller from 2100? Or are you just very bad at arithmetic?

Comment: @JoeBlow, in my experience, it is almost never two different places. I have participated in taking animals to variously named slaughterhouses or packing plants. After leaving the animals, they never left until we retrieved the packages of meat. The meat needs to be as fresh as possible, so the animals are slaughtered, processed, and packed on site. A strictly meat processing plant may be different in that they are usually used by hunters. "_From deer to hog, and elk, but no dog. You pop 'em, we chop 'em_" -  Rockwall Deer Processing

Comment: @RonMaupin - good one, thanks for that insight.  Actually I deleted my comment based on what you have said.

Comment: The first three words that jumped up in my mind when I read the title were *slaughterhouse*, *dairy* and *apiary*.

Comment: @P.O. it is more for an average Joe. I will try to explain to some people about the main companies in the town I live.

Comment: @TonyK It was Friday. :)

Comment: @Beta "Apiary" is a place where bees are kept.  So far as I know, no-one kills bees for meat.

Comment: @Graham: [Wrong again!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeybees_(food)) Are they considered a delicacy in Yunnan because they are difficult to find, or are they difficult to find because they are considered a delicacy? The article doesn't say.

Comment: @TonyK Interesting.  (Note to self: never underestimate what bizarre things people will eat. :)  In that case though the local dialect word for it would probably be more relevant, considering the general use of "apiary" in the rest of the world.  Certainly bees are not exactly "animals like cows, pig and chicken", and you don't need the same slaughterhouse process!

Comment: @Graham: I did mention the *title*, didn't I?... Yes, yes I did.

Comment: @Beta And I did mention the actual question, didn't I?  Yep.  Had your comment continued "...but then I read the question and realised *apiary* wasn't relevant to what the OP wanted", then no worries.  We're supposed to be answering the question, not the title.

Comment: @Graham: So you're telling me that my Comment should have been a Comment, not an Answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **High-processing packinghouse**

is the term you're looking for.

Here are the distinctions made in the Netherlands for all type of meat  processing plants, from a [governmental website](http://www.fao.org/WAIRDOCS/LEAD/X6114E/x6114e04.htm).

### Categories of slaughter-plants

> Plants for red meat slaughtering may be categorized on the basis of
>   the final products. A plant that processes meat into products such as
>   canned, smoked and cured meats is significantly different from a plant
>   with facilities for slaughtering without further processing.
>
> Slaughterhouses and packinghouses (slaughtering and meat processing)
>   may each be divided into two categories on the basis of the quantity
>   of waste produced (EPA 1974).

## Slaughterhouses:

> - Simple slaughterhouse:
>
> A plant that slaughters animals and does a very limited amount of by-product processing. Its main products are fresh meat in the form
>   of whole, half or quarter carcasses or in smaller meat cuts.
>
> - Complex slaughterhouse:
>
> A plant that slaughters and does extensive processing of by-products. Usually at least three of the following operations take
>   place: rendering, paunch and viscera handling, blood processing, and
>   hide and hair processing.

### **Packinghouses**

> - Low-processing packinghouse:
>
> A plant that both slaughters and processes fresh meat into cured, smoked, >canned and other meat products. Only the meat from
>   animals slaughtered at the plant is processed. Carcasses may also be
>   sold.
>
> - High-processing packinghouse:
>
> A plant that also processes meat purchased from outside. Sometimes, a high- >process packinghouse has facilities for tanning
>   operations.
>
> There are also plants that do not slaughter themselves but restrict
>   their activities to the processing of meat (**meatpacking**). These plants
>   have a waste production comparable to that of a simple slaughterhouse.

It's also  the official name in the US see this extract from [Cornell Law School](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/40/432.41)

> For the purpose of this subpart: **High-processing packinghouse** means a
>   packinghouse which processes both animals slaughtered at the site and
>   additional carcasses from outside sources.

Comment: Perhaps the asker is looking for a technical term but I wouldn't expect a person who's not connected to the meat industry to have any clue at all what a "high-processing packinghouse" is. Indeed, if I went out on the street right now and started asking people "What's a high-processing packinghouse", I doubt anyone would even guess that it had anything to do with meat.

Comment: _Slaughterhouse_ is the common-language umbrella term (in AmE).

Comment: By the context the person will either understand the meaning or look up in a dictionary, op never said he was writing for the lowest common denominator, why would you assume that. I'm all for using the most appropriate term and educate the reader whenever possible. Hey, why not calling that a "the meat thingy down the road"...

Comment: This answer is terrible. Aside from the intelligibility concerns raised by other commenters, it's also too specific. It's like getting the question "what do you call physical exertion intended to increase physical fitness" and answering "one-handed push-ups" instead of "exercise".

Comment: no it's like saying " what do you call physical exertion intended to increase physical fitness by pushing oneself with only the power of one arm?" and answering "one handed push-ups" Your comment is useless.

Comment: I laughed when I saw this answer! "High-processing packinghouse" might as well be Martian as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: PO - unfortunately you're just wrong, dude.  @user2357112 's explanation is perfect and need not be repeated.

Comment: well you did not read the question then, the question was very specific, the answer too.

Comment: There was absolutely nothing in the question about also processing meat purchased from outside, yet somehow, you felt the need to specifically include an adjective for that.

Comment: "A place where the animals like cow, pig and chicken are killed, cleaned and have its meat and parts processed into bagged foods like bacon, ham, beef, etc." -- of all the terms you gave, "low-processing packinghouse" matches most exactly. However, as others have pointed out, few if any people are going to actually know what a (high or low processing) "packinghouse" is. "Slaughterhouse", on the other hand, is widely known and understood. You could also try "meat packing plant".

Answer (score 15):

The UK National Careers Service gives these categories of workplaces and employee roles, which suggest how things are generally split up here.

> - abattoirs – as a slaughterman or woman, humanely killing and preparing
>     livestock
> - wholesale meat factories – cutting, de-boning and preparing
>     carcasses before they are sold to retailers
> - butcheries – specialising
>     in preparing meat in line with instructions from caterers
> - meat or
>     poultry processing plants – producing and packing products for the
>     retail and catering industries

I'm not sure that we have one term which covers all eventualities. Individual establishments will also carry out different parts of the processing. My local abattoir calls itself an 'abattoir and cutting plant' and does basic butchery for small livestock producers who take in live stock and collect the boxed up bits a few weeks later after the meat has hung and been butchered, but other establishments will only take larger jobs and ship out as soon as the carcass is skinned and cleaned.

Comment: It is a very good answer, I think the word I am looking doesn't exists in English, because here in Brazil we have in a single, but big, company that embraces all of theses categories and on the other countries they do in different companies. Here is the website of one of them: https://www.brf-global.com/brasil/

Answer (score 8):

Probably "meat packing plant" comes closest in the US, as it implies all stages of the preparation.  "Slaughterhouse" could be interpreted as referring to only the front-end slaughter operation (though I vaguely recall that this is referred to as the "kill room" in the Hormel operation about 50 miles southwest of here).

Answer (score 6):

One keeps food that must be chilled in a fridge, but animals are slaughtered at a ***slaughterhouse*** (compare *matadouro* in Portuguese: place for killing; in French, *abattoir*), after which their remains are then installed in refrigerated units to keep them cold so they don't rot as fast.

Comment: I think, by checking Google [images](https://www.google.it/search?q=Frigor%C3%ADfico&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwib6eraq-LRAhXD2hoKHRchBsoQ_AUICCgB&biw=1242&bih=580#imgdii=1MFoXfGUF0pbQM%3A%3B1MFoXfGUF0pbQM%3A%3BxrYILneKDzi3KM%3A&imgrc=1MFoXfGUF0pbQM%3A) for *frigorífico*, the OP means this type of factory http://www.cronica.com.py/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/10-f1-5.jpg

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I'd be surprised if, at a slaughterhouse/abattoir, they just killed the animal and did nothing else to it. I suspect your factory photo is part of a slaughterhouse/abattoir.

Comment: I think slaughterhouse just define a sector. I was looking at the website of one of this companies, and it seems they call themselves as food company. https://www.brf-global.com/brasil/en/about-brf#what-we-do

Comment: @AndyT But the workers in the image don't actually do the killing/slaughtering, so I think there is a significant difference.

Comment: @tchrist - "Abattoir" is also an English word. Personally I (living in South East England) hear it much more frequently than "slaughterhouse"; though dictionary.reference.com doesn't express a BrE preference for it, or an AmE preference for slaughterhouse. It didn't seem worth me posting it as a competing answer.

Answer (score 6):

In the UK we'd call it an **[abattoir](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/abattoir)**

> a place where animals are killed for their meat

*Cambridge Dictionary*

Answer (score 2):

Since [BRF S.A.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BRF_S.A.) was given as an example of the type of company you are looking to describe with this word, simple terms like *abattoir* or *slaughterhouse* are certainly not appropriate.  This type of company is usually described as a **[conglomerate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conglomerate_(company))**.

The word itself is not specific to the food industry, so in English this is specified with extra qualifiers in the phrase - ie (from the Wikipedia entry):

> BRF, formerly Brasil Foods S.A. (BM&FBovespa: BRFS3 / NYSE: BRFS), is a Brazilian food conglomerate created from the merger of Sadia S.A. into Perdigão S.A.

The term `Frigorífico` is not standard Portuguese but is a specifically Brazillian term.  The closest standard Portuguese term is **[Abatedouro](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abatedouro)**, which is a cognate of *abattoir*.  This doesn't seem to convey the same meaning of *meat processing and distribution conglomerate*, however, that you are looking for.

In fact, as best as I can tell, *frigorífico* actually means something more like an *industrial meat packing plant* rather than a food industry conglomerate like BRF.  I would guess that a very large company like BRF would *own* many subsidiaries that you could call *frigorífico*, but the term seems too restrictive to describe the entire company.  In fact, the [Portuguese Wiki describes BRF](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/BRF) as (emphasis mine):

> A BRF [...] é um **conglomerado brasileiro** do ramo alimentício

It then goes on to describe several corporate acquisitions :

> Em outubro de 2011 a BRF faz duas aquisições na Argentina, comprando as companhias Avex (**empresa frigorifica**) e Dánica (líder argentina na fabricação de Margarinas) por 150 milhões de dólares.[14][15]

So, BRF is big enough to have *acquired* several *frigorífico* companies, but itself is a larger organization, even producing goods like frozen foods, margarine, etc, that are well beyond the scope of purely meat products.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest ***Meat Locker*** as fitting this definition (although this may be a specific usage in the American Midwest).

As well as being the name for the actual cooler in which slaughtered meats are kept (similar to the "Frigorífico" translation), a meat locker can also refer to a facility that slaughters, processes, and sells cuts of meat and further processed products such as sausages, hams, and bacon.  Some meat lockers also serve ready to eat foods, such as tenderloin sandwiches or barbecue, or offer additional services such as processing deer or wild pigs during hunting season.